# how to add a link of other apps in a current app

Tags: android

I have a bunch of similar apps which the user might be interested in downloading. 
I have a button 'get more of this' so when the user clicks on this button , it shows a link of other apps. Clicking on that link should take him to the download page in the 
android market. I tried google but couldn't find any answers.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this for each app:

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=your.app.package.name"));
marketIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

You can also do a search:

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:your.app.package.name"));
```

Comment: Do you need to put that marketIntent in manifest file? What exactly should when the code works? Can you give more details? thanks

Comment: No, you would just put that code in your onClick listener for the 'get more of this' button you were referring to.

Comment: The app is crashing. These are logs which I am seeing.


03-15 11:03:54.887: E/AndroidRuntime(572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 11:03:54.887: E/AndroidRuntime(572): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=nik.trivia flg=0x40080000 }
03-15 11:03:54.887: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
0

Comment: Also when you say 'your.app.package.name' its just a package name which  is already thr on the market right? Can I just search for my app name?

Comment: Looks like either you are running on a device without the Market installed or you're running the emulator without using Google's APIs.

Comment: Ooops I guess i forgot to add Google API's can I add it now?

Comment: No, just create a new emulator image from AVD Manager.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8899/discussion-between-nikhil-and-abdullah-jibaly)

Comment: I configured the build path to point to the google API;s and used an emmulator having the target as google API's. its still not working